# Cleaning up an SQL Query

Tags: sql

My district has the following SQL Query and it seem pretty long winded to me. I'm not sure I'm including all the information that is needed as I'm not the normal SQL person who works on this but told them I would get some help from an online resource that has helped me a lot with PHP etc. The problem with it is that it is taking a very long time to run. Is there anything that is being done in the below code that is bad practice and if changed would help to speed up the query.

```
USE newburgh 
SELECT DISTINCT  sh.name, 
       sh.number, 
       s.studentnumber, 
       s.lastname, 
       s.firstname, 
       s.grade, 
       s.gender, 
       s.raceethnicity, 
       ad.term1Absences + ad.term2absences + ad.term3Absences + ad.term4Absences AS [Total Absences], 
       ad.term1Tardies + ad.term2Tardies + ad.term3Tardies + ad.term4Tardies AS [Total Tardies],
       CASE p.code 
         WHEN '5806' THEN 'R' 
         WHEN '5817' THEN 'F' 
         ELSE ' ' END AS 'Free/Red Lunch', 
       CASE pp.name 
         WHEN 'Document' THEN 'Yes' 
         ELSE ' ' END AS 'Document', 
       at.code, 
       at.description, 
       MIN(at.date) AS [Start date], 
       MAX(at.date) AS [End date], 
       COUNT(DISTINCT at.date) AS [Total days]
FROM dbo.student s 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_AttendanceDetail at 
    ON s.personID = at.personID 
    AND s.calendarID = at.calendarID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_ProgramParticipation p 
    ON s.personID = p.personID 
    AND p.code IN ('5817', '5806') 
    AND p.endDate IS NULL 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_ProgramParticipation pp 
    ON s.personID = pp.personID 
    AND pp.name = 'Document' 
    AND pp.endDate IS NULL 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SchoolYear sy 
    ON s.endYear = sy.endYear 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.v_SchoolCurrent sh 
    ON s.schoolID = sh.schoolid 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.v_AttDailyTermSummary ad 
    ON s.personID = ad.personID 
    AND s.calendarID = ad.calendarid
WHERE sh.name = (@Location) 
  AND sy.label IN (@Year) 
  AND at.code IN ('80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89')
GROUP BY sh.name, sh.number, s.studentNumber, s.lastName, s.firstName, s.grade,    
   s.gender, s.raceEthnicity, at.code, at.description, p.code, pp.name, ad.term1Absences,   
   ad.term2Absences, ad.term3Absences, ad.term4Absences, ad.term1Tardies,   ad.term2Tardies, 
   ad.term3Tardies, ad.term4Tardies
ORDER BY s.studentnumber, at.code
```

Comment: At first glance I cannot see any blatant changes that would help. However a good place to start would be checking the indexes that you have and considering adding more. In Sql management studio there is a button beside the execute that will also show you the query plan and will show you which step is hogging up the process time; that may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me.  You can change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `dbo.SchoolYear` and `dbo.v_AttendanceDetail`, because your where clause will cause them to behave like inner joins. For anything else, you'd need to include explains, table structures, etc.

Comment: Also, you may get better advice if you identify what RDBMS you are working with (SQL Server, MySQL?)

Comment: DISTINCT *and* GROUP BY in a query like this... Seems unlikely that you need both. But it is hard to determine what to change without knowing how the tables involved are related to one another. Two joins to `dbo.v_ProgramParticipation` also look unnecessary, but again, I couldn't tell how to combine them (if at all) without knowing what they are used for here.

Comment: Also, there appears to be only one table whose columns are aggregated. Perhaps you could aggregate it separately and join the aggregated result set as a derived table thus avoiding the long GROUP BY list and possibly helping the performance. Knowing your schema better would help to be sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

query performance is a big issue to be just able to solve it by viewing the script.
Things you can check:

- Are all your join options primary keys or at least indexed?
- How many tuples is this query returning?

How many tuples does each relation have?
Try to analyze the process of the query so you can know what path the motor is using.

I can't think of anything specific which is slowing this down. Those are a lot of joins anyway.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

one easy bit that jumps out at me is `COUNT(DISTINCT at.date) AS [Total days]`. it seems to me that shouldn't be needed at all. you already calculated all the absences so you should be able to subtract absences from some known number of days (possibly from `SchoolYear`) to get the total days attended.

the same thing sort of applies to the `[Start date]` and `[end date]`. it would be faster if these values were simply stored in the `student` table at the cost of storing some duplicated data. This argument could be made for the total number of absences too. if those totals were stored in the `student` table then you wouldn't need to join the `v_AttDailyTermSummary` table at all.